# Android share picture on facebook with hashtag

Tags: android, facebook, sharing

Here is my problem: I would like to make my app able to share a picture on facebook with an automatic setted hashtag.
I searched on facebook documentation, and I tried some code.

I am currently able to login and post a picture, no problem at all, but I can't see the hashtag (or any error about)

Here is my code:

```
     sharedialog = new ShareDialog(this);

     SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                        .setHashtag("#FollowTheSun")
                        .build())

                .build();

        if (sharedialog.canShow(content)) {
            ShareDialog.show(this, content);
        }
```

What I do wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I changed nothing, but it's somehow currently working.

Comment: You're right, it works with the above pasted code. Thanks for the solution. I was about to pull my hair out.

Comment: hi , did you get any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

**please try this one**

```
public void shareFb() {


    if (isFacebookExist()) {


        if (CheckButton.isChecked()) {


            SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(updateImage)//image location
                    .build();


            if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                        .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                                .setHashtag("#YOURHASHTAG")
                                .build())
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }

        } else {

            SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(updateImage)
                    .build();


            if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }

        }


    } else {
        showToast(" Facebook is not install.");
    }

}
    private boolean isFacebookExist() {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is if (CheckButton.isChecked())

Comment: CheckButton is Xml Check button and here i check that condition what happen if the button was clicked